# Android Studio selectivily compile

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Not sure if that's possible at all. I've added a `debugCompile` to some library in my app's gradle, now when I compile my code in `release` of course I get a compile error. The questions is this is there a way not to compile / include to the code a certain line if I'm in release, without using `flavors` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing you can do if you don't want to use `flavors` is to put your code which uses some debug-specific libraries into the `if` clause like so:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    // do your debug-specific actions here
}
```

On release build this `if` clause with the code inside it will be thrown away by compiler as unused. But, you still will have the compile-time error saying that there is some code which uses undefined libraries. The solution is to include the gradle `compile`  directive in release build also:

```
compile 'com.foo:bar:1.2.3'
```

The second thing is to use some third-party java-preprocessors, like [this one](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor).

The choice is yours, but I'd prefer to stay with flavors. You can always write some abstract class which has 2-3 methods which make use of debug-specific library. In release extension of this class you leave these methods empty, while in debug version you write some code.